# python: how to get all the students of one class and save it to into one place?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, tuples, pivot-table

i have a dataframe like

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['cla1', 'cla1','cla1','cla2', 'cla2','cla3'],
                   'student': ['stu1', 'stu2', 'stu3', 'stu4', 'stu5', 'stu6']})
  class student 
0  cla1    stu1
1  cla1    stu2
2  cla1    stu3
3  cla2    stu4
4  cla2    stu5
5  cla3    stu6
```

what i want is this but i don't know how to make it.

```py
  class student 
0  cla1    stu1, stu2, stu3
1  cla2    stu4, stu5
2  cla3    stu6
```

is there any function like `pivot_talbe` to make it?

Comment: Something like this `df.groupby('class', as_index=False).aggregate(list)`?

Comment: @Heike, thx, it solved my problem. what's more, is is possible to remove the square brackets at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx to [Heike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840947/heike),

```py
df.groupby('class', as_index=False).aggregate(list)

# result
  class             student
0  cla1  [stu1, stu2, stu3]
1  cla2        [stu4, stu5]
2  cla3              [stu6]
```

I wonder if there is a way to remove the square brackets at once?